# VBA Optimize array handling

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I ran up against the limit of the amount of items I could put into a single array... I also ran into the limit of the number of line continuation characters I was able to use... So I had to break this function into two arrays.  I really hate that I had to use two arrays, but it does work. Does anyone have any suggestions how I could tighten this code up? Maybe take out the "insert character into a cell" step and just jump right to the color?...

Have fun

```
Sub Why_Not_Zoidberg()

    Dim Inx As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim A1() As Variant
    Dim A2() As Variant
    Dim Rng1 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

A01 = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1)


A02 = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

    x = 0
    For i = 1 To 24 'Rows
    For j = 1 To 64 'Columns
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Select
            With Selection
                .Value = A01(x)
            End With
        x = x + 1
    Next j
    Next i
    x = 0
    For i = 25 To 48 'Rows
    For j = 1 To 64 'Columns
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Select
            With Selection
                .Value = A02(x)
            End With
        x = x + 1
    Next j
    Next i

    'SET RANGE
    Set Rng1 = Range("A1:BN48")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    'Add Colors
    For i = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
      For j = 1 To Rng1.Columns.Count
        Select Case Rng1.Cells(i, j).Value
            Case 3
                Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 3, 74)
            Case 2
                Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Case 1
                Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(1, 1, 1)
            Case 14
                Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 153)
        End Select
        'For k = 1 To 10000: Next k, adds a delay to animate
      Next j
    Next i
    With Rng1
        .ColumnWidth = 2
        .RowHeight = 14.25
        .ClearContents
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not about maximum number of elements in an array, it's about maximum number of arguments when calling a function (the `Array()` function). If you have a lot of data, put it somewhere like a text file or a sheet, and read it into an array with a loop.

Comment: So you're typing the values in VBA and then printing them into a worksheet. As per the comment above, I suggest you do the opposite. After all, hodling large amounts of data is the job of the worksheets, the *precessing* is the job of VBA.

Comment: You can set the values on a whole row at once with `Range("A1").Resize(1,n).Value = Array(1,1,1,2,2,...)` where `n` is the number of items in the row

Comment: What is the logic behind the values in the array? Can you store them in text file and read them instead of hard coding them?

Comment: The color setting seems to be better suited for a conditional formatting rule, rather than direct cell manipulation.

Comment: In a formal programming situation I would totally use a text file and conditional formatting, but this is a wild bit of crazy fun... an Easter egg of sorts.  A self contained VBA / macro that draws a silly character.  It's a memory burner.  I'm just looking for an efficient way to draw it.  So I think of pixels, which can be color filled cells which can be defined in an array... but I do agree that the grid seems like it could somehow be compressed or made into a formula... I remember karnau maps for reducing truth tables, but that's as far as I got.  It's crude, so I'm asking for advice

Comment: Karnaugh maps may help for really simple patterns, but for simple bitmaps I would explore [Run length-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) first.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is highly compressible, is a shame not to make use of it!

Solving your question in a straight way, you may `Split` a long composed string:

```
Dim sa As String
sa = "2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2"
sa = sa & " " & "2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 3"
'
' ...
'
sa = sa & " " & "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2"
a = Split(sa)
```

Your array will be a string array, but arithmetic is not a problem in VBA.
Alternativelly, you could pack your data (4 bit). Example:

```
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
Array(&H01234567, &H89ABCDEF, &H11112222, ...)
```

This way you could extract your data with little bit manipulation.
But really think about compression!

Comment: OMG compression!

Comment: That's what I was going for next... there has to be a way to express all those data points as a formula that is positional dependent.   I have no idea how to do compression.        I started using arrays because I don't want to have a text file.  My first successful attempt used a text file, but then everyone would need the text file.    So now I'm looking at other ways to achieve the end result... I'm building complexity in stages.   Thanks for all the feedback.   This is a fun learning project.   More on compression please

Answer (score 1):

I am going to offer a different approach to this problem.

1. Create a text file with the values you want to set, arranged by rows and separated by commas (see .csv file format). For example [use this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QWpWtpqR) file.
2. Read the file row by row, parse each line into an array of strings, convert the strings into numbers and *use the entire array* to set the values of each row on the worksheet.
3. Apply conditional formatting to the worksheet to display the correct colors based on the values

**For Example:**

```
Dim rng_1 As Range
Set rng_1 = Range("M26")

Dim fs  As TextStream, txt_row As Variant
Dim val_row() As Variant
Dim n As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Set fs = fso.OpenTextFile("data.csv", ForReading, False)
j = 0
While Not fs.AtEndOfStream
    ' Read a line of text and split into array of strings
    text_row = Strings.Split(fs.ReadLine, ",")
    'Need to convert text values into numeric type
    n = UBound(text_row) + 1
    ReDim val_row(0 To n - 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        val_row(i - 1) = Val(text_row(i - 1))
    Next i
    ' Write values of entire row onto worksheet
    rng_1.Offset(j, 0).Resize(1, n).Value = val_row
    ' index the row
    j = j + 1
Wend
fs.Close
```

[image: result]

PS. There is rarely a case where `.Select` and `Selection` are needed. It is far easier and more robust to read/write directly from range references with the `Range()` object. In fact, avoid using `.Cells()` also and use *named range* references together with `.Offset()` and `.Resize()`. For example

```
Dim A() as Variant
A = Range("my_table").Resize(10,10).Value
A(1,1) = 1 - A(1,2)*A(2,1)
Range("my_table").Resize(10,10).Value = A
```